# MySQL - Search All Databases

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a stack of databases, all the same structure.  What I need is the value of the table "config", column "serial" and the database name for each database.

Is there a way of iterating through the databases automatically and getting the database name and the value of its config.serial?

Cheers,
Gwen

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379116/mysql-loop-through-databases-and-run-a-stored-procedure-on-it

Comment: I can get the database names with 

SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA

but that's as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: What platform are you doing this on? Depending on whether you are on Windows or a Unix (Linux or OS X), the exact mechanism for looping through all the databases will be slightly different

Comment: Unix - sorry I should have thought to mention that!

Comment: Thanks WeaklyTyped, I had seen that but it's way beyond my current understanding, I'd be more likely to use the select schema_name... and make Excel write individual select statements for each record :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT <db>.<table>.config,<db>.<table>.serial,<otherdb>.<othertable>.config,<otherdb>.<othertable>.serial FROM <db>.<table>,<otherdb>.<othertable> WHERE ...
```

Comment: Hi h3rrmillier, thank you for your suggestioin, this wouldn't be dynamic would it? I'd have to fill in the databases (over 1000)?

Comment: take a variable $database to store the values. ex: `$database = "database$i"`. Where you have the `$i` as a variable and you can use a loop to get values as **database0,database1,...** and so on.

Comment: Or since you're looking for specific databases with certain tables called config and serial you could do this: `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%config%' OR TABLE_NAME LIKE '%serial%'`

Comment: ^ that will return all databases with config or serial tables in it.  you can put the results into a loop to build your query